# Creating a chart using Data from an Custom JR DataSource

Tags: java, jasper-reports

im having a hard time figuring out how to pass data from a custom JR Datasource to a chart, I got the data passed to the report however whenver I try to pass it to a chart it doesnt show anything.
The Values im trying to pass are the mean, the days, and the SD to create a levey jenning report 
heres the code below for the datasource class:

```
package MyDataAdapt;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField;

public class GoImplementation implements JRDataSource {

    public GoImplementation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /** 
     * For this data adapter the informations are embedded in the code
     */

    private static final  Integer[] lotNum = {33301141,33301143 };
    private static final Integer[] level= {1,3};
    private static final double[] mean= {4.49,457.04};
    private static final double[] SD= {0.30,22.58};
    private static final double[] CV= {6.79,4.94};
    private static final Integer[] N= {54,53};
    private HashMap<String, String> capitalCities = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static final double[] mean2= {3.92,465.95};
    private static final double[] SD2= {0.35,31.11};
    private static final double[] CV2= {9.04,6.68};
    private static final Integer[] N2= {333,340};

    private static final String[] department = {"GENERAL"," "}; 
    private static final String[] instruementArray = {"ARCHITECT cI4100-I1SR"," "};
    private static final String[] test = {"Human Chronic Gonadotropin (BhCG) {7K78}(mIU/mL"," "};
    private static final String[] method = {"NONE"," "};
    private static final String[] reagentArray = {"ABBOTT"," "};

    private static final String[] month = {"January, 2015"," "};
    private static final String[] shift = {"All"," "};
    private static final String[] qcProduct = {"MULTICHEM IA PLUS(05P76-10)"," "};
    private static final Integer[] days = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};


      HashMap<String, Integer> lotp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     HashMap<String, Double> meanp = new HashMap<String, Double>();
      HashMap<String, Double> sdp= new HashMap<String, Double>(); 
      HashMap<String,Integer> dayp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();



     /**
     * Variable to store how much records were read
     */
    private int counter = -1;



    /**
     * Variables to store the number of fields, and their names, in the report
     */
    private HashMap<String, Integer> fieldsNumber = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    /**
     * Method used to know if there are records to read.
     */
    private int lastFieldsAdded = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        if (counter<lotNum.length-1) {
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called for every field defined in the report. So if i have 2 fields it is called 2 times for every record, and 
     * for each of them it must provide a value.
     * The parameter can be used to understand for which field is requested, in fact it contains the name of the requested field. This 
     * data adapter is done with the goal of return two values, a name and an age. An easy option would be expect a field with the name 
     * "Name" and one with name "Age". But we can do something more flexible, in this case we will enumerate all the fields requested and 
     * and the first two will be assumed to be for name and age, for all the others will be returned an empty string. So we can have a report 
     * with more than two fields, but the name and the age will be returned each time only for the first two. 
     * 
     * If this example is too much complex refer to the method getFieldValue2, where is shown the first explained, and simple solution, where we 
     * expect two fields with a precise name.
     */
    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField jrField) throws JRException {
        Integer fieldIndex;
        if (fieldsNumber.containsKey(jrField.getName())) {
            fieldIndex = fieldsNumber.get(jrField.getName());

        }
        else {
            fieldsNumber.put(jrField.getName(), lastFieldsAdded);
            fieldIndex = lastFieldsAdded;
            lastFieldsAdded ++;
        }
        if (fieldIndex == 0) return lotNum[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 1) return level[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 2) return mean[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 3) return SD[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 4) return CV[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 5) return N[counter];

        else if (fieldIndex == 6) return mean2[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 7) return SD2[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 8) return CV2[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 9) return N2[counter];
        else if (fieldIndex == 10) return department[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 11) return instruementArray[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 12) return test[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 13) return method[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 14) return reagentArray[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 15) return month[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 16) return shift[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 17) return qcProduct[0];
        else if (fieldIndex == 18) return days;
        return "";
    }


    /**
     * Return an instance of the class that implements the custom data adapter.
     */
    public static JRDataSource getDataSource(){
        return new GoImplementation();
    }

}
```

The Jrxml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.9.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.9.0-cb8f9004be492ccc537180b49c026951f4220bf3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="GraphReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b0db03f9-1d9d-4eb5-8f2e-bc1174d4b926">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CustomDataPackage\DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="LeveyJen" uuid="7a90870e-2a65-494c-9a60-0c66448362de">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CustomDataPackage\DataAdapter.xml"/>
        <parameter name="Mean" class="java.lang.Double">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.js.ic.ds" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter"/>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="SD" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <parameter name="Days" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="days" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The dAYS Used]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Mean" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Mean]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="SD" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Standard Deviation]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="Lot#" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The lot number]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="CV" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Coeficent Variation]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <group name="Mean">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Mean}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Mean" class="java.lang.Double" evaluationTime="Early">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[4.49]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SD" class="java.lang.Double" evaluationTime="Early">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[.30]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="days" class="java.lang.Integer" evaluationTime="Early">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Lot#" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The lot number]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Level" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The level]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Mean" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Mean]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="SD" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Standard Deviation]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CV" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Coeficent Variation]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="N" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Sample]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cMean" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Cummulative Mean]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cSD" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Cummulative Standard Deviation]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cCV" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Cummulative Variation]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cN" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Cummulative Sample]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="department" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Department]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="instrument" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Instrument]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="test" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Test]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="method" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Method]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="reagent" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Reagent]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="month" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Month]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="shift" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Shift]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="qcProduct" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The Product Used]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="days" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[The dAYS Used]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="626">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="200" height="200" uuid="80fb1a9e-e915-4f0a-8841-5ec4dc3e3e62">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="LeveyJen" uuid="b73b13da-6c82-476a-b05b-a76ceb8b0ace">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="870bbd63-dd2a-4a61-8488-ae55835df694">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:groupHeader groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupHeader>
                        <jr:groupFooter groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="dc2219e0-b6bb-4957-bf7e-ebad553c307d"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[days]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="c508b8f7-a940-4c21-8704-65df0d812521"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{days}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="b7ae7382-8aa7-466f-96f8-ec5549e7ea7f">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:groupHeader groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupHeader>
                        <jr:groupFooter groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="4c916eef-3956-41c7-81b5-86ed59d8f816"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Mean]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="3fba2b84-0d0a-4be9-8e39-2e883dc20962"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Mean}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="f50bd22f-deee-4ff7-b001-7e5515386adf">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:groupHeader groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupHeader>
                        <jr:groupFooter groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="960b3408-1558-4c43-9f90-366aef4bf4fa"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[SD]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="ce6ed33b-3b8a-4be7-96e9-4d6032342ba2"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SD}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="6ccc302d-bfbf-49c2-b1a9-1574cace4c20">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:groupHeader groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupHeader>
                        <jr:groupFooter groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="80e5d6b0-074c-4c5a-9a71-32d7e5ecbef9"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Lot#]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="0d711de1-e894-4c2f-8247-f95a9ae14b14"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Lot#}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="40" uuid="361c4990-a417-4dbe-8fad-354daf2da30c">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:groupHeader groupName="Mean">
                            <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        </jr:groupHeader>


                <jr:groupFooter groupName="Mean">
                        <jr:cell style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                    </jr:groupFooter>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="cb377e1c-7426-45d5-b063-c70ba13d3189"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[CV]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="a5b3191c-e675-4018-8727-6afec6544feb"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CV}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <lineChart>
            <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="0" y="426" width="555" height="200" uuid="e6cccf0d-fe31-4417-ab27-f8a13aa142ad"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <categoryDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="LeveyJen" uuid="49b8c004-a74d-4b9f-a772-9f0996c2c7fc">
                        <datasetParameter name="Mean">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Mean}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="SD">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SD}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Days">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{days}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                </dataset>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{Mean}]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{days}]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{SD}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
                <categorySeries>
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{days}]]></seriesExpression>
                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{days}]]></categoryExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{SD}]]></valueExpression>
                </categorySeries>
            </categoryDataset>
            <linePlot>
                <plot/>
                <categoryAxisFormat>
                    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                </categoryAxisFormat>
                <valueAxisFormat>
                    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                </valueAxisFormat>
            </linePlot>
        </lineChart>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You need to add your jrxml also make it minimal remove all that is not related to chart see [mcve].

Comment: thank you for the heads up and i just added the jrxml to the page

Comment: I can't see you referencing your datasource class GoImplementation   + there is a table and a lot of other stuff is this using same datasource?

Comment: yes its using the same datasource, from the GoImplementation class

Comment: or at least trying to figure out how to reference it to populate the chart based on the jrdatasource class

Comment: You know that datasource is consumed, you need to rewind it before using it again? Also I only see you passing connection to chart, not the datasource

Comment: how do i pass the datasource to the chart?

Comment: ive tried calling the get datasource in the datasource expression. new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRDataSource

Comment: and also how do i rewind the datasource?

Comment: I'm not really following you Bill, the datasource is yours GoImplementation, why new JRDatasource? *How do I rewind the datasource", again the datasource is yours, eg. make a method that returns the datasource rewinded?

Comment: oh that's what you meant my apologies the term rewind had me confused, so in order for me me to get the data populating in the chart, id have to call the same data source but what i don't understand is how and where to do that, i've seen examples where people have passed the data source as a parameter to the subreport however its never to a chart, so im not sure which option to use and how to go about it

Comment: is it the Implementation i call when im trying to put it to a table for the use JRDatasource expression?